# Estimate median of Cauchy distribution

Tags: statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

Motivated by [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375208/is-cauchy-distribution-somehow-an-unpredictable-distribution) question, assume we have independent samples $(X_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ from a Cauchy distribution with unknown median $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and scale parameter $b$. What is the best way to estimate $a$?

More precisely, for $d$ some distance between probability distributions of your choice what choice of $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ minimizes

$$
\sup_{a\in\mathbb{R}}d(\mu_{a,f},\delta_{a}),
$$
where $\mu_{a,f}$ is the distribution of $f(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ when $X_i$ have median $a$,
and how does the minimum behave as $n\to\infty$?

For example, if we use $f(x_1,\dots,x_n):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$, then $f(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ has the same distribution as $X_1$ and thus any distance between $\mu_{a,f}$ and $\delta_{a}$ will be independent of $n$ and in particular not converge to zero.

Comment: Have you applied your criterion and examined the **sample median**? It is at least a passing estimator. See [Journal of the American Statistical Association
Vol. 55, No. 290 (Jun., 1960), pp. 322-323 by Paul R. Ryder](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2281744).